# Node.js how to keep on reading a text file

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js

I'm trying to read a text file. The text file is updated everytime an event occurs in my c program in linux.

Here's my code.

```
var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs');

var filetoread = fs.readFileSync('this_is_a_log.txt');

server = http.createServer();

server.on('request', function(req, res){
res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
res.end(filetoread);
});

server.listen(9000);
```

How can node.js continue reading the text file so the page keeps updated everytime the text file is modified. I don't want to use a delay or timeout, I want to do it real time. Is there a function in node.js that can do this. Also I don't want to use tail.

Comment: Sounds like you want to mix [node-tail](https://github.com/forward/node-tail) with [socket.io](http://socket.io/).

Comment: lol I didn't know there was an easy way of doing this, using node-tail

Comment: @robertklep Yes, that is my plan. Node.js will be the server and socket.io will get the data from node.js. I will be using this with embedded device. The text file is updated with 1 as true and 0 as false.